# Choppy Audio/Video Playback Experience

Tags: 10.10

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 since its beta release. I had been updating it regularly.
Sine the day of up-gradation the audio and video playback is choppy regardless of any format. I waited until 10th of October.

This was not an issue in Lucid. How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the solution mentioned here

Choppy video in Maverick
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1592120&page=5

Answer (score 2):

This really could be any number of problems. It also depends what Video/Audio playback your talking about (Flash, MP4, MP3, etc). Also what kind of Graphics card do you have (or do you even have one, most laptops use [integrated graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#Hybrid_solutions)). If you could **provide more information** (like computer model, graphics card, etc) we might be able to help more, but for now I'll give you my best guess.

**Flash**:
<strike>Forget about Flash, it sucks!</strike> Flash can be a resource hog, however if you want to browse the web it's kind of important to have. What browser are you using? This can make a huge difference as Firefox can have multiple addons that provide Flash support. You can use Adobe's proprietary implementation, or you can use a non-proprietary implementation. I've always had better success with Adobe's versions (but that's just me).

[Google Chrome](http://chrome.google.com) on the other hand comes with Flash support. (**Note**: Chromium which is the open-source implementation of Chrome does not come with Flash as far as I know). I currently run Chrome on Ubuntu 10.10 and the Flash works amazingly well (and I have a [integrated graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#Hybrid_solutions)). So far Chrome or Flash has not crashed once.

**MP3/MP4/Video/Audio Playback**: To ensure you get the best possible playback I would recommend making sure you have [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg). It supports just about every format you'll use (QuickTime, MP4, Real Player, Windows Media Player related codecs, etc).

Once you have this installed these programs/drivers the only thing that will cause choppy playback is your graphics card, or having other programs running that are using your graphics card ([Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/) for example).

If you do have an [integrated graphics card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#Hybrid_solutions), increasing the amount of [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) in your system can help. Increasing [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) is also one of the cheapest upgrades you can do. If you have a Desktop, you most likely have a Graphics Card, in which case you can get a new one that will support better video playback.

Comment: My hardware: VAIO FW230J, Intel centranio, C2D 5800, 3GB, Intel GMA 4500MHD.

Comment: This problem does not seems to be related with GPU. MP3 audio playback is choppy as well.

Comment: @Shoaib: Technically you don't have a GPU, but I understand what your saying. Have you tried installing FFmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to simply upvote this, but I did not have the karma =(

Just to set the record straight, the original solution was posted by NightwishFan on the ubuntu forums - thank you NightwishFan

Post #2 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1588889

> Workaround for glitchy (crackling, skipping) audio is to open:
>   `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
>
> Find the line that looks like this and add `tsched=0`.
>
> ```
> load-module module-udev-detect
> ```
>
> It should look like this:
>
> ```
> load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
> ```
>
> Note:  This fixed an issue I had with a soundblaster PCI-e SB1040 card in Ubuntu 11.10 with choppy audio on AMD.  The card did not work prior to Ubuntu 11, and was then choppy until this fix with tsched=0 is applied to default.pa.
>
> Save and reboot (or just log out).
>
> Note this will not fix a problem with that specific chipset in the bug
>   report with a muted speaker/headphone. I have no idea where to go with
>   that one. Lidex and I have been trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

[See if installing the restricted multimedia codecs in this site helps](http://open-help.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-make-ubuntu-1010-maverick.html)